# Table name of "Static blocks" and "Cms pages" in database magento?

Tags: mysql, magento

i need export a database only of the static blocks and cms pages of magento, but i dont know whats is the extactly table name of this database, i hope can help me with this, thanks for your patience, regards and good vibes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For static block `cms_block` and cms page `cms_page`.

For import and export cms page and static blocks you can also use this free extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-cms-pages-static-block-importer.html

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Amny thanks Keyur!, its solved. I got it! thanks again!

Comment: @Sara - can you please share with me how you solved it. Im looking to do the same thing.

Comment: This extension works **ONLY** on regular page structure, not on Nested page structure !